# How to get feature_names after encoding text avg_word to vec?

Tags: machine-learning, nltk, feature-extraction

I am performing analysis on donor_choose data-set.Created a glove words file for essays and encoded essays using average word to vec .
Now, i want to get feature_names.How to perform that?

I performed BOW on essays and extracted feature names too.But couldn't perform the same with average word to vec.I extracted features fro BOW through model and get_feature_names().But,how to apply the same on average word to vec,where we are not using any model but the vector of that word.

"""Encoding Essay- Bow"""

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

vectorizer.fit(essay_train)

clean_essay_bow_X_train = vectorizer.transform(essay_train)

clean_essay_bow_X_test = vectorizer.transform(essay_test)

for i in vectorizer.get_feature_names():

feature_names_bow.append(i)

"""Encoding Essay- avgw2v"""

import pickle

with open('glove_vectors', 'rb') as f:

```
model = pickle.load(f)

glove_words =  set(model.keys())
```

def avgvectorizer(data):

```
avw2v_data = []

for sentance in tqdm(data.values):

    vector=np.zeros(300)

    cnt_words=0;

    for word in sentance.split():

        if word in glove_words:

            vector+=model[word]

            cnt_words+=1

    if cnt_words!=0:

        vector/=cnt_words

    avw2v_data.append(vector)

return avw2v_data
```